# How to write Numeric Unsigned, four bytes integer using the Apache Commons libs?

Tags: java, numbers, apache-commons

I have to write in a buffer some integer values. But in the API is specified that the number is **Integer, Numeric Unsigned and must have at maximum 4 bytes** .

How to write Numeric Unsigned, four bytes integer using the Apache Commons libs?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this a number of ways using the built in libraries, so I don't know how you are intenting to use Apache Commons.

```
DataOutputStream dos = ...
out.writeInt((int) unsignedIntValue);
```

similarly

```
ByteBuffer bb = ...
bb.putInt((int) unsignedIntValue);
```

or for little endian format

```
ByteBuffer bb = ... .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
bb.putInt((int) unsignedIntValue);
```

ByteBuffer allows you to change the byte order to little endian if you need that.

Comment: In a text format it can be almost any size of 1 or more bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I found the class [EndianUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/EndianUtils.html#writeSwappedInteger%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

But I'm not sure if it's what I'm looking for.